# How I show theme selection page with thumbnails to everyone?

Tags: 6, theming

I want to create a menu link for theme selection to users (also for anonymous users). I have installed the [Switchtheme](http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme) module but it shows only theme names; my requirements are to show the theme name with thumbnails, just like we see in "User account -> edit -> theme configuration" or with normal theme selection in `admin/build/themes`. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to permissions page `sitename.com/admin/user/permissions`

search for `switch theme` and apply for roles.

[Switchtheme](http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme) Also provides some Blocks see Block configuration page

Thats all.

Comment: Yes I have configured that but I don't want block with Theme names only. I want to show theme configuration page as we see in "admin/build/themes/" with thumbnails.

Comment: Its actually `select different theme`